# how to stop running default sms app when one sms with special word receive

Tags: android

How to stop running default sms app for example "Go sms pro" when one sms with special word receive,and my app open with that sms.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The default SMS app will be notified and "Go SMS Pro" does know your code.

You do not have control over other applications.

Comment: Nothing. You can't do what you're asking.

Comment: when go sms is not install my app run perfect :-(

Comment: Your application needs to be the default SMS app to achieve what you want. Doing so without is not possible.

Comment: Your app so be set to default by the user.

Comment: I didn't downvote mate. You got your answer: for security reasons, you can't do what you want. Sorry.

Comment: security reasons?? :-o

Comment: Yes, obviously. Like Marcin said: luckily you cannot do anything ^^ You're asking about an app not being the default SMS app, being able to activate upon keywords (detect and run) while disabling the default SMS app of the user...

Comment: Then it should of course: your app will receive SMS, up to you to parse its content.

Comment: Can i set my app as default  then if the received sms not contains keyword run secound sms app for example "gosms"?how do it?

Comment: AFAIK there is no API for that either. Again, the usage you ask for is something that Android doesn't have and I explained why. I doubt you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you find a bug that would let you do so, you will not be able to do that.